# GoormIDE | Can't run mongod in GoormIDE Container

Tags: mongodb, ide

For context: I am creating a website in html+ejs+mongoose which I had created locally on my pc. Since I want to see the website running on another device besides my local computer, I uploaded the files on GitHub and then cloned it into an online IDE, in this case, GoormIDE, to do that.

As the title above had said, I can't run mongod in a container even though I have enabled mongoDB in the container setup. I created a file which is mongod which runs the code `mongod --nojournal` so that I will not have journal files in my directory. I kept receiving this error code:

```
2020-12-27T05:24:49.128+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=802 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=goorm

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.22

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 1741806fb46c161a1d42870f6e98f5100d196315

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 1024 MB of memory available to the process out of 7771 MB total system memory

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { journal: { enabled: false } } }

2020-12-27T05:24:49.135+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file., terminating

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown, waitTime: 10000ms

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] Shutting down the global connection pool

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Killing all operations for shutdown

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] Shutting down free monitoring

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Shutting down full-time data capture

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down the HealthLog

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Dropping the scope cache for shutdown

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting

2020-12-27T05:24:49.136+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Because of this, I can't start the website because it needs mongoDB/mongoose in order to run the server.

It seems that mongod/mongoDB doesn't have a data directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer guys!

I just need to put `-dbpath ./data/db` after `mongod`

With that, I created a directory of data/db where I will store all the data from mongoDB.

so now I edited the file that I created named "mongod" with: `mongod --nojournal -dbpath ./data/db` and everything works once again. I feel pretty silly not knowing this but I hope I will never make this mistake again.